# upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, Django + uWSGI + nginx, React as frontend

Tags: django, reactjs, nginx

I am getting this error

> upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header
>   from upstream

in Nginx's error.log when sending a post request to Django on send_mail, as the response it returns

> 502 Bad Gateway

and also CORS error

> has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource

CORS is enabled on Django, less secure apps are turned on on Gmail.

Comment: How have you configured the CORS headers on your Django app?

Comment: When you say "CORS is enabled on Django" how have you configured that?

Comment: Yes, i have installed it on my django project, added to installed apps, i set cors_origin_allow_all to true, also added on top of middlewares

Comment: I don't have this problem on development, it is on production.